# OpenGL, shaders and strange lightning on notebooks

Tags: opengl, graphics, shader, glew, light

I have to write a simple OpenGL game. When I'm running it on my PC everything is good. Unfortunately when I run it on laptop it has some problems.

PC:
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/11/i48o.png

Laptop:
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/543/zdpf.png

This is my code for fragment shader:

```
varying vec3 normal, lightDir[3], eyeVec;
uniform sampler2D myTexture;

const float cos_outer_cone_angle = 0.73;

void main (void)
{
    vec4 final_color = (gl_FrontLightModelProduct.sceneColor * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient) + 1.2*((gl_LightSource[0].ambient) * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient);

    for(int j=1;j<2;j++){
        final_color+=(gl_FrontLightModelProduct.sceneColor * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient) + ((gl_LightSource[j].ambient) * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient);
    }

    vec3 L[5];
    vec3 D[5];
    vec3 E = normalize(eyeVec);
    vec3 R[5];
    float specular[5];
    float cos_cur_angle[5];
    float cos_inner_cone_angle[5]; 
    float cos_inner_minus_outer_angle[5]; 
    float spot[5];
    vec3 N = normalize(normal);
    float lambertTerm[5];

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        L[i]=normalize(lightDir[i]);

        D[i]=normalize(gl_LightSource[i].spotDirection);

        cos_cur_angle[i]=dot(-L[i], D[i]);

        cos_inner_cone_angle[i] = gl_LightSource[i].spotCosCutoff;

        cos_inner_minus_outer_angle[i] = cos_inner_cone_angle[i] - cos_outer_cone_angle;

        spot[i] = clamp((cos_cur_angle[i] - cos_outer_cone_angle) / cos_inner_minus_outer_angle[i], 0.0,1.0);

        lambertTerm[i] = max( dot(N,L[i]), 0.0);

        R[i] = reflect(-L[i], N);

        specular[i] = pow( max(dot(R[i], E), 0.0), gl_FrontMaterial.shininess );

        if(lambertTerm[i] >0.0){
            final_color += gl_LightSource[i].diffuse * gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse * lambertTerm[i] *1.5* spot[i];

            final_color += gl_LightSource[i].specular * gl_FrontMaterial.specular * specular[i] *3.0* spot[i];
        }
    }

    gl_FragColor = final_color *  texture2D(myTexture, vec2(gl_TexCoord[0]));           
}
```

And this is for Vertex Shader:

```
varying vec3 normal, lightDir[3], eyeVec;

void main()
{   
    normal = gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal;

    vec3 vVertex = vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex);

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        lightDir[i] = vec3(gl_LightSource[i].position.xyz - vVertex);
    }
    eyeVec = -vVertex;
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;

    gl_Position = ftransform();     
}
```

PC graphics is Radeon HD6770 and Notebook GPU is Geforce GT325M.

I don't know where is the problem. Is it shaders or terrain loading or what.

Comment: any warnings on the laptop when compiling/linking?

Comment: This suggests that something you are doing with your OpenGL calls or in your shader programs is undefined behavior, and the drivers on the PC just happen to handle it the way you want it to.